# How to change data temporarily before passing view

Tags: php, laravel, model, eloquent

I am passing one row to the blade. Also doing this for lots of page. But in one page, i need to edit some datas in row, like this.
This is eloquent:

```
$meta = SeoOptimization::find($id)->first();
```

it has `title`, `description` and `keywords`

what i want to do is, change title and description before passing to the view.

I do like that:

```
$meta['title'] = $category->translate()->title;
```

But now worked. Also tried this:

```
$meta->title = $category->translate()->title;
```

That didn't worked too.

```
dd($category->translate()->title);
```

is successfully return what i want. 
How can i pass this, with $meta->title? Any suggestion?

Still can't pass to view, they are chaning but changed in controller. Can't pass.

Comment: Can you please show the code that you use to pass it to the view? And the usage from the view? Because using `$meta->title = 'Some other value';` should work okay. I just tried something similar in my code.

Comment: show ur passing method and view

Comment: return view('views.cagegory', compact('category', 'meta')); 
It passing original meta to the view.

Answer (score 0):

try to use like that for example by using `toArray()` method

```
$user = User::where('id',1)->first();
$user->name = "Jignesh";
return view('views.cagegory')->with(['user' => $user->toArray()]);
```

in view

```
@isset($user)
     <h1>{{$user['name']}}</h1>
@endif
```